# Is it possible to determine whether an instance method was called from within a prototype method?

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
function Foo(x) {
    this.bar = function() { return x; /* but not always */ }
}

Foo.prototype.baz = function() {
    return this.bar(); // Case 2 - should return x
};

var f = new Foo(3);
f.bar(); // Case 1 - should return undefined 
f.baz(); // should return x which is 3 in this case
```

---

So, `bar` is an instance method of `f` which is an instance of `Foo`.
On the other hand, `baz` is a prototype method of `Foo`.

What I would like is this:

`bar` should return `x` (the argument passed into the constructor function), but only if it is called from within a prototype method (a method of `Foo.prototype`). So, `bar` should check whether the current execution context is a `Foo.prototype` function, and only then `bar` should return `x`.

In Case 1, the current execution context is Global code, so the return value of the `bar` call should be `undefined`. (By this, I mean: I want it to return undefined in this case.)

However in this case 2, the current execution context is Function code of a `Foo.prototype` function, so the return value of the `bar` call should be `x`.

Can this be done?

---

**Update:** A real-world example:

```
function Foo(x) {
    this.getX = function() { return x; /* but not always */ }
}

Foo.prototype.sqr = function() {
    var x = this.getX(); // should return 3 (Case 2)
    return x * x;
};

var f = new Foo(3);
f.getX(); // should return undefined (Case 1)
f.sqr(); // should return 9
```

Case 1: `getX` is called "directly" -> return undefined
Case 2: `getX` is called from within a prototype method -> return x

Comment: i guess you could use arguments.callee.caller, but it is really deprecated and shouldn't be used

Comment: Why do you need it? I can't find the usefulness of it...

Comment: @Martin Look at the update in my question. I am passing a number into `Foo`. I want that number to be accessible to prototype methods, but I don't want that number to be retrievable directly without using a prototype method.

Comment: @Martin The expression `arguments.callee.caller == Foo.prototype.baz` (when placed inside `bar`) indeed does evaluate to false in the first case and true in the second case, which makes it a valid solution.

Comment: I know, but it is deprecated and thus not really ideal, read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103598/why-was-the-arguments-callee-caller-property-deprecated-in-javascript - in ECMAScript 5 Strict Mode they won't exist at all.

Comment: @Martin I have tried to answer my question below. I use `getX.caller` instead of `arguments.callee.caller`. Would that be OK?

Comment: I wouldn't do that since that is not even part of the ecma standard. if you wish to go that way, be sure to test it through all borwsers... i think you'll find it won't work in a few of them :)

Comment: @Martin `caller` seems to be supported in all browsers (even IE6). See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller

Comment: @Sime: In that case, use it :) It all comes down to what you want and need. I am only here to offer  advise :)

Answer (score 0):

> In Case 1, the current execution context is Global code, so the return value of the bar call should be undefined.

you're using a closure, that is why the method getX has acces to the variable x. It's javascript behaving as intended.

Comment: Method getX having access to the variable x is not the point here. I want getX to return undefined if its caller is not a prototype method.

Answer (score 0):

So this is my own solution:

```
function Foo(x) {
    function getX() { 
        return getX.caller === Foo.prototype.sqr ? x : void 0;
    }
    this.getX = getX;
}

Foo.prototype.sqr = function() {
    var x = this.getX();
    return x * x;
};

var f = new Foo(3);
console.log( f.getX() ); // logs undefined 
console.log( f.sqr() ); // logs 9
```

As you can see, I had to define `getX` as a local function of the `Foo` constructor (and then assign this function to the instance via `this.getX = getX;`. Inside `getX`, I explicitly check whether `getX.caller` is `Foo.prototype.sqr`.