# why is second function parameter in comment block? just curious

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, comments

I found this code and I dont understand purpose of comment block in parameters:

```
if (!Array.prototype.some)
{
  Array.prototype.some = function(fun /*, thisp*/)
  {
    var len = this.length;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in this && fun.call(thisp, this[i], i, this))
        return true;
    }

    return false;
  };
}
```

In my opinion it could be normal second parameter and this row could be deleted then:

```
var thisp = arguments[1];
```

Comment: Can you ask the original author of the code?

Comment: Dude, it's just a comment! it has no meaning, it's just there! who knows what he meant to do with that parameter?

Comment: It seems like this question might be better directed to the author of the code in question... [EDITED to add: oh look, others got there first and said the same. I'll leave this here as a reminder to myself to refresh before commenting :-).]

Comment: @Gareth: I was under the impression that SO nowadays refreshes while you type ...

Comment: It doesn't seem to have done so for me on this occasion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of `Array.prototype.some` built in to Firefox has an arity of 1, i.e. it accepts one argument. In order to implement the second optional argument without changing the arity the replacement code accesses the second argument via `arguments[1]` instead.

I don't actually know what the EcmaScript specification has to say about the arity of `Array.prototype.some`.

Answer (score 1):

If `Array.prototype.some` is defined, the original method had a second parameter which is `thisp`, but since it is not defined, the author defines his/her own method that mimics the functionality.

The author expects that the caller passes the second parameter which is `thisp`.
HTH.

Comment: Yes, but he could save one row of code avoiding this. Unreasonable behavior for me. :)

Comment: @Luckylooke see this <https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Compatibility>.

Answer (score 0):

you're right, it should be a parameter, because 1. using the functions `arguments` within a function is [expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147389/accessing-the-arguments-object-is-expensive-huh) and 2. it's hardwired into the function, although it can stay `undefined` in the actual loop. The method shouldn't be in production code, I'd say. Testing some more, it's not clear what the second parameter actually does anyway. The [MDN shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is a strange duck, but maybe I've missed something.