# How to find how many arguments function defines?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I know `arguments.length` method , but this returns the number of arguments the function was called with.

What I need instead is the number of arguments that function requires, so for example

```
function myFunc(arg1,arg2,arg3) {
  alert("number of passed args:" + arguments.length);
  alert("number of required args:" + /*the code I'm asking for*/);
};

myFunc('some arg');
```

So myFunc() would return two alerts saying 1 and 3.

Any way to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another, he **deprecated** [`arguments.caller.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/caller) property holds this value.

```
function myFunc(arg1,arg2,arg3) {
    alert("number of passed args:" + arguments.length);
    alert("number of required args:" + arguments.caller.length);
}
```

Another method to get the number of formal parameters is by using the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Length) property of the function. The function's name has to be known for this method:

```
function myFunc(arg1,arg2,arg3) {
    alert("number of passed args:" + arguments.length);
    alert("number of required args:" + myFunc.length);
}
```

Comment: About this 'deprecated' is not so simple: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1335595/393087 , they changed name for it , functionality will be saved. (as I understand it thru my leaky english skills)

Comment: @rsk82 `arguments.callee.caller` points to the calling function, not the function itself.