# Access argument name string inside the function

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to access arguments name strings?!

```
function myFunction (a, b, c, d, e, f) {
    var obj = [];
    [].forEach.call(arguments, function(arg) {
        obj.push({
            // question is how to get variable name here?
            name: "a",// "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"
            value: arg, //a, b, c, ,d, e, f
        })
    });
 return obj;
}

myFunction(1,2,3,4,5,6); // return [{name: "a", value: 1}, {name: "b", value: 2}...]
```

Note: I know using `arguments` is not a good practice. I want to know if this even possible or not?

Comment: How could `myFunction` return anything if it doesn't have a return statement?

Comment: I have yet to find a basic way to retrieve the names of the argument variables. Values is cake, names not so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
function myFunction (a, blabla, c, somethingElse, e, f) {
    var obj = [];
    //'(a, b, c, d, e, f)' 
    var tmp = arguments.callee.toString().match(/\(.*?\)/)[0];
    //["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"] 
    var argumentNames = tmp.replace(/[()\s]/g,'').split(',');

    [].splice.call(arguments,0).forEach(function(arg,i) {
        obj.push({
            // question is how to get variable name here?
            name: argumentNames[i],
            value: arg
        })
    });
    return obj;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(myFunction(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)));
//Output-> [{"name":"a","value":1},{"name":"blabla","value":2},
//          {"name":"c","value":3},{"name":"somethingElse","value":4},
//          {"name":"e","value":5},{"name":"f","value":6}]
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XVvbM/)

Comment: Nice hack. `callee` is what I never thought about.

Comment: Yep, I agree. But consider reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee too

Comment: @KooiInc Yes, `callee` is forbidden *only in strict mode*, but not in entire javascript at all.

Comment: +1 For finding a creative solution, though I'd agree that `.callee` shouldn't be used when you could use the function name.

Comment: @amnotiam I have tried to not hardcode the function's name, but sure `arguments.callee` can be replaced by `myFunction`.

Comment: @Engineer, it's not forbidden in non strict js, but it *is* deprecated for a number of reasons, very well explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103598/why-was-the-arguments-callee-caller-property-deprecated-in-javascript.

Comment: @KooiInc But who was talking about `argument.callee.caller` ?? `arguments.callee` was, what I meant.

Comment: @Engineer: the linked SO-answer is about both `callee` and `caller`, if I understood right

Comment: @KooiInc See the `RobG`'s comment. And it silly to think, that `argument.callee` is added *only* for supporting `inline anonymous function recursion`. The core advantage of `arguments.callee`, is making things *generic*. If you have enough time and interest, you might look at [goog.base](https://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/trunk/closure/goog/base.js) lib, especially `inherits` and `base` methods. It will be very interesting to alter `arguments.callee.caller` concept in `goog.base` method. What will you do?!! Ugly hardcoding?!!!

Comment: @Engineer: RobG where? Anyway, don't get all worked up on it. I justed added the comment as a side note. Feel free to use and/or advocate the use of `arguments.callee[.caller]`. I'll give you one more link for further reading: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.arguments. Let me repeat: I am really not forbidding anyone anything.

Comment: @KooiInc thanks for the link.But I'm not changing my opinion related to `argument.callee`. You might agree, that in the most cases such performance problems(caused by `argument.callee`) will not be 'visible',but on the other hand developer should write *easy-maintainable* code, *generic* code, *non-hardcode*,which is more important for the developer. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Are the function parameter names definied in the function definition, as you've written above? If so, you can just create an array in the function:

```
function myFunction(a,b,c,d,e,f) {
  var argNames = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
  ...
}
```

`arguments` will only ever contain a simple array of the arguments passed to the function. There is no default mapping from arguments to parameter names. That I'm aware of anyway

Comment: Yes, but you don't have any choice in the matter. There's no practical way to access function parameter names. Maybe you can clarify the context in which you're attempting this; perhaps there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
function myFunction( _obj ) {

    var obj = [],
        names = [],
        args = arguments,
        len = function(o) {
            var a = [];

            for (var i in o) a.push(i);

            return a;
        };

    for (var i in _obj) names.push( i );

    [].forEach.call( len(_obj), function(a, b) {
        obj.push({
            name: names[b],
            value: args[0][names[b]]
        });
    });

    return obj;

}

console.log( myFunction({
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4,
    e: 5,
    f: 6
}));​​​​
```

Here is a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qJsQ7/)

Comment: He wants the name, so the first argument would have `name:"a"`, then `name:"b"`, `name:"c"`, etc. You're assigning `"a"` for every argument.

Comment: @Mohsen I was able to change it. Instead of inputting the arguments individually, I made it able to take an object literal instead. This version *does* work.

Comment: Sorry, you have changed the question.

Comment: What do you mean, this functions as you have intended?

Answer (score 0):

For completeness: you can't use *named parameters* in javascript. If you want to use them (and thus be able to identify the parameter names), a workaround is to supply an object:

```
function myParams(params){
  var ret = [];
  for (var l in params){ 
   if (params.hasOwnProperty(l)){
    ret.push(l);
   }
  }
  return ret
}
myParams({a:1,b:2,c:3,d:null,e:null,f:null,g:11});
//=> [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
```

[See also...](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Named_parameters#JavaScript)
And to be really complete: [see this also](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/javascripts-arguments-object-and-beyond/)

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke toString on the function and then use some kind of RegEx to parse result.

```
    function someFunction(a,b,c){}
    var functionString = someFunction.toString(); //return "function someFunction(a,b,c){}"
    var args = functionString.match(/^function (?:.*?)\((.*?)\)/);
    if(args[1])
    {
        var argsNames = args[1].split(",");
    }
```

I've tested it on FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Since item.product_image2 is a URL string, you need to put it in quotes when you call changeImage inside parameter.

My Function Onclick

```
items+='<img src='+item.product_image1+' id="saleDetailDivGetImg">';
items+="<img src="+item.product_image2+"  onclick='changeImage(\""+item.product_image2+"\");'>";
```

My Function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeImage(img)
 {
    document.getElementById("saleDetailDivGetImg").src=img;
    alert(img);
}
</script>
```