# ES5 "strict" and arguments.callee

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why was the arguments.callee.caller property deprecated in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103598/why-was-the-arguments-callee-caller-property-deprecated-in-javascript)

In ES5 strict mode (i.e. `"use strict"`) the `arguments.callee` variable that refers to the current function is no longer available.

For recursive functions it's obviously sensible to use the function's own name.  However there are times when I might want to use properties of `arguments.callee` (i.e. `.length`, `.prototype`) without having to use the name of the current function.

Can anyone explain what apparent problem was (allegedly) solved by removing it?

Comment: Bad practice, pretty much. All cases of `arguments.callee` either can be solved in a more elegant manner, or should not be solved.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103598/why-was-the-arguments-callee-caller-property-deprecated-in-javascript.

Comment: As for the edge cases: that's part of why I don't use strict mode anymore... :P

Comment: @ close voters - that question is about a specific sub-property of `arguments.callee`.

Comment: @Alnitak: The answer "accidentally" is for a big part about `.callee`.

Answer (score 5):

From [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Strict_mode).

> arguments.callee substantially hinders optimizations like inlining
>   functions, because it must be made possible to provide a reference to
>   the un-inlined function if arguments.callee is accessed.

Comment: Do you happen to know why the reference is not required in case of a named function?

Comment: @pimvdb Because the name of the function is always made available in the local scope of the function itself.

Comment: I'm as curious as @pimvdb is; but I don't see how you've answered his question. If you can provide a reference to the un-inlined version of the function via `return <name>`, then that's no different from doing so via `return arguments.callee`. Is it? If so, how?