# Function to get function name inside function?

Tags: javascript

To get a function's name inside a function I can use this code:

```
function getmyname() {
    var myName = arguments.callee.toString();
    myName = myName.substr('function '.length);
    myName = myName.substr(0, myName.indexOf('('));
    alert(myName); // getmyname
}
```

however I need to run this a lot of times, so I'd rather use a function that does it, so it would look like:

```
function getmyname() {
    alert(getfname()); // getmyname
}
```

so `getfname()` would get the name. How can this be done?

Comment: Read this: [Why was the arguments.callee.caller property deprecated in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/235760/14104)

Comment: Probably also worth asking yourself if you really need to do that.

Comment: What would `getfname()` do with the name? Just return it? If so, why wouldn't you just reference the name in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may pass local arguments to `getmyname` function and use `callee.name` instead of parsing:

```
function getmyname(args) {
    return args.callee.name;
}

function getname() {
    alert(getmyname(arguments));
}

getname();  // "getname"
```

Comment: And it's worth pointing out that, since the parsing in the OP's code is not needed, there's really no need to have a separate `getmyname` function - just use `alert(args.callee.name)`

Comment: @Stuart Yes, `alert(arguments.callee.name)` to be precise. However, I just follow the OP's question.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I didn't know you could just use that. The answer is right though.

Answer (score 0):

`.name` is a property which *function objects* own.

```
function getmyname() {
    return arguments.callee.name;
}

function getname() {
    alert(getmyname());
}

getname(); // alerts "getmyname"
```

---

A word of caution:

> arguments.callee alongside other properties, is obsolete in
>   ECMAscript5 strict mode and will throw an error when accessed. So we
>   would need to return getmyname.name, which is obviously not really
>   elegant because we could directly return that string