# TypeError: arguments.callee.caller is not a function

Tags: jquery

I am hoping that someone can help me to correct some issues that I am having with a custom script. I took over the management of a site and there seems to be an issue with the following code:

```
/*  jQUERY CUSTOM FUNCTION 
------------------------------ */
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box').mouseenter(function(){
   var elmID = "#"+this.id+" img";
   $(elmID).fadeOut(300);
});

$('.ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box').mouseleave(function(){
   var elmID = "#"+this.id+" img";
   $(elmID).fadeIn(300);
});

var numbers = $('.ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box').size();

function A(i){
    setInterval(function(){autoSlide(i)}, 7000);
}
A(0);

    function autoSlide(i) {
        var numbers = $('.ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box').size();
        var elmCls = $("#ref").attr("class");
        $(elmCls).fadeIn(300);
        var randNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*numbers)+1);
        var elmClass = ".elm"+randNum+" img";
        $("#ref").attr("class", elmClass);
        $(elmClass).fadeOut(300);
        setInterval(function(){arguments.callee.caller(randNum)}, 7000);
    }
});
```

The error that I am seeing in the console on Firebug is "TypeError: arguments.callee.caller is not a function. I am just getting started with jQuery and have no idea how to fix this issue.

Any assistance with altering the code so that it still works but doesn't throw up all of these errors (if I load the site and let it sit in my browser for 10 minutes I have over 10000 errors in the console) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Probably due to browser upgrade. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/103598/2454376

Comment: You have `A` that calls `autoSlide` in an interval, but then `autoSlide` calls *itself* in an interval!  Why do you have 2 intervals?

Answer (score 4):

Inside the `setInterval`, `arguments` is probably not what you think it is.  When called, every function has its own `arguments` array.  When `setInterval` is ran, the function passed to it is called, so `arguments` is for that function (the anonymous one).

I see you're trying to use `arguments.callee.caller` to get the function that called the interval, `autoSlide` in this case.  That won't work.  The function passed to `setInterval` is *not* called by `autoSlide`, it's called by the browser.  All `autoSlide` did was call `setInterval`, so `arguments.callee.caller` is `null`.

Since you know the name of the function, `autoSlide`, you can just use that.

```
setInterval(function(){
    autoSlide(randNum);
}, 7000);
```

---

**UPDATE**: Are you sure you need a `setInterval` inside `autoSlide` in the first place?  Your code calls `A(0)`, which calls `autoSlide` with a `setInterval` already.  Do you really need *both* intervals?

Comment: To put it another way (for the OP's benefit) functions invoked by `setInterval` are run with a clean [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

Comment: @apsillers: Yep, exactly.  I know what I'm talking about, but I'm not the best at explaining :-)

Comment: Well, I think with 59k rep, you're not *that* bad at explaining :)