# Get the name of the anonymous variable that contains the function

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I have the functions

```
function getCallingFunctionName() {
    alert(arguments.callee.caller.name.toString();
}

var bob = function() {
    ...
    getCallingFunctionName();
}
```

When the code is run the value alerted is an empty string is returned. I need to return

```
 bob
```

I CANNOT change the original functions (im dealing with a large project with thousands of functions etc.

```
var bob = function bob() {
    ...
    getCallingFunctionName();
}
```

Any one got any other ideas ? Its not critical to have but basically to help with debugging.

Comment: If an anonymous function has a name, it isn't anonymous is it?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what problem you're trying to solve. But if you need an identifier, can't you simply add a local variable identifying the name of the function?

Comment: `arguments.callee.caller` is deprecated. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103598/why-was-the-arguments-callee-caller-property-deprecated-in-javascript/235760#235760

Comment: okay guys thanks for your help, i was lookinf for something a shortcut, it doesnt appear possible, so ill do a longwinded version

Comment: good point @Matt Burland :)

Answer (score 2):

What if you try to do something like this:

```
function getCallingFunctionName() {
    try {
        throw new Error();
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

var bob = function() {
    getCallingFunctionName();
}
```

It will give you something like this:

```
Error
    at getCallingFunctionName (<anonymous>:4:15)
    at bob (<anonymous>:12:5)
    at <anonymous>:2:1
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:581:39)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:540:52)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:459:21)
```

which you can use for your purpose, i.e. to extract function name. The only sad thing is that IE supports [Error.stack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Stack) starting from version 10.

Comment: i love answers like this, there's always a 'way'

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way, that requires a little extra effort/code, but maybe it suits you:

```
var cache = {};

var bob = function () {
    getCallingFunctionName();
}

function getCallingFunctionName() {
    alert(cache[arguments.callee.caller.toString()]);
}

cache[bob.toString()] = "bob";

bob(); //bob
```

So you are basically caching the function string representation (which is the complete function body) and using it as a key for the actual function name. Afterwards you can access the name, using again only `func.toString()`. Of course, this requires that you don't have two functions who have the exact same body.