# Why does arguments.callee hurt performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, function, optimization

The alternative to using [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee) is to simply name the function, as such:

```
// Snippet 1, using arguments.callee:
(function(){
    document.body.innerHTML += 'qwe';
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1);
})()

// Snippet 2, using naming:
(function f(){
    document.body.innerHTML += 'qwe';
    setTimeout(f, 1);
})()
```

What is stopping the JavaScript engine/compiler from automatically optimizing Snippet 1 into Snippet 2 above? Is there some *inherent* limitation existing?

- [MDN's argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) basically boils down to:

  > ..`arguments.callee` substantially hinders optimizations like inlining
  >   functions, because it must be made possible to provide a reference to
  >   the un-inlined function if `arguments.callee` is accessed.

  However, if we manually name the function and call it via it's name, we are *already* providing a reference to the function, and thus "hindering optimizations like inlining functions".
- [Olliej's argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/235760/1048572) is basically "inlining and tail recursion [becomes] impossible in the general case [whereas it is possible if naming is used]". However no evidence is provided and it seems like a handwave (Also see the comments below his post).

Why is function-naming more performant than using `arguments.callee`?

Comment: I think the MDN is referring to a named function expression, not an anonymous function expression assigned to a variable (i.e. `(function f(){})`).

Comment: The first line in ["*Why was arguments.callee removed from ES5 strict mode?*" section of the MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee#Why_was_arguments.callee_removed_from_ES5_strict_mode.3F) says "*(adapted from [a Stack Overflow answer by olliej](http://stackoverflow.com/a/235760/578288))*"

Answer (score 0):

By my reading, MDN is not saying "it's hard to provide a reference to the un-inlined function"; rather, it's saying "it's hard to ensure that, when you access `arguments.callee`, you get a reference to the un-inlined function".

(This is only half an answer to your question, because it's still not clear to me why `arguments.callee` should be so much harder to keep up-to-date than the rest of `arguments`, or than `this`. So the argument, as it stands, is not obviously compelling. But that's what I think MDN is saying.)

Comment: But couldn't the compiler ensure that accessing `arguments.callee` would return a reference to the function, since it could (among other alternatives) observe that `arguments` wasn't changed before the call to `arguments.callee`? *Anyway not to be rude, but I think this post is more of a comment...*

Comment: @Pacerier: I guess that, yes, an intelligent compiler could do that, but it is overly complex (and therefore not done). The comments on olliej's post lead in the same direction.

Comment: @Bergi, Hmm I don't think that's the case (since they often do  much more complex stuff)... For this, isn't it simply a matter of setting a flag indicating `arguments.callee` is modified if the body of the function does an assignment to it? The decision to deprecate it in `strict` seems to suggest that there is some hard-wired limitation which couldn't be overcome by future compilers.

Comment: @Pacerier: Given that the `arguments` object can be saved in a variable, passed to other functions, and so on, I don't think it's all that simple for the interpreter to determine statically whether `arguments.callee` is modified.

Comment: @Pacerier: Also -- I considered posting it as a comment rather than answer. I decided to post it as an answer because its point is that the premise of your question is mistaken. If this is not an answer, then there *is* no answer, and the question should be closed/deleted; but I don't want the question to be closed/deleted, because it's intelligent and valuable, just founded on a minor mistake.

Comment: @ruakh, Ic, but the compiler could easily know whether or not the `arguments` object is assigned to a variable or passed to a function, and only then (since it's more of a special case than the general case to tinkle with the `arguments` object) give it a red flag isn't it?

Comment: @Pacerier: I believe so, yes. (Or at least, it could rule it out.)