# Is there a way to refer to the current function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

I am writing several similar versions of a certain recursive function, for comparison purposes. My functions look like this:

```
function rec1(n) {
    /* some code */

    rec1(n-1);
}
```

Then, to create another version, I copy & paste and get:

```
function rec2(n) {
    /* some other code */

    rec2(n-1);
}
```

etc.

Instead of having to change the name of the function in each version, I wonder if there is some way to refer to the "current function" (just as in a Unix script it is possible to refer the the "current script" with the $0 variable), so that I can write:

```
function rec1(n) {
    /* some code */

    $this_function$(n-1);
}
```

Comment: `arguments.callee`, though it is forbidden in strict mode. Why not just use the name? Or you may be better of creating a function factory if the recursive call is always at the end and always has the same criteria.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee), but it's deprecated.

Better just [name the functions](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/), and give them all the same names:

```
var rec1 = function rec(n) {
    /* some code */

    rec(n-1);
};
var rec2 = function rec(n) {
    /* some other code */

    rec(n-1);
};
```

… where `rec` is scoped the current function, and points to the current function.

Comment: Also FWIW, [here is an explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/235760) of why `arguments.callee` is deprecated.