# Why using setInterval with self-invoking function a better approach?

Tags: javascript

I saw an answer about the correct usage of `setInterval()` function. It was said that

```
(function(){
   // do some stuff
   setTimeout(arguments.callee, 60000);
})();
```

guarantees the next call from setTimeout isn't made before the previous has ended. Why using self-invoking functions makes this happen?

Comment: This "correct usage" is actually incorrect, since `arguments.callee` is deprecated and forbidden in strict mode, for various reasons. Instead, use named functions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103598/why-was-the-arguments-callee-caller-property-deprecated-in-javascript/235760

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using an immediately-invoked function expression doesn't make it happen, it's using `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()` that does it. The mechanism of `setInterval()` will not really start the next iteration before the first one has finished, unless the handler does something like begin an asynchronous operation. But by using `setTimeout` instead, it's possible to have more control over the delays between iterations.

Also it really shouldn't be written that way. Instead:

```
(function f() {
  // code
  setTimeout(f, 60000);
})();
```

Using `arguments.callee` is a bad idea when it's not strictly necessary.