# Caller and Calee returns an error

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript and trying to check the caller and calle properties of Arguments object.

Here is my code

```
function showFunc() {
    var funcname = arguments.calee.name;
    console.log(funcname);
}
showFunc();
```

Now it displays an error in console saying

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Please tell me where am I going wrong.

Comment: it's arguments.callee.name not arguments.calee.name

Comment: i think its a typo please verify

Comment: if you're learning JS, please skip over `caller` and `callee`, because they're from an ancient form of JS, and are not used in modern JS, as the information they provide do not lead to good programming patterns

Comment: @Mike I am reading Javascript: the definite Guide... 6th Edition

Comment: See MDN: [*arguments.callee*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee) and [*arguments.caller*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/caller).

Comment: Then I strongly recommend skipping those sections. The 1998 `caller` and `callee` properties belong in 1998, not 2015. Modern JS is modular, and knowing "who callled a function" is an antipattern (your code should work regardless of who called it, or who's being called).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans—I understood *callee* as a way of function expressions being recursive without the need for a name. Many languages have a way of referring to the currently executing function without using its name, it's not a bad thing in itself.

Comment: So is there any other way to check for caller and callein 2015?

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini—callee still works, just not in strict mode. Caller is removed from the current specification (ECMAScript 2015) but it will still work for some time yet (but writing new code to use it isn't a good idea).

Comment: @RobG yeah but just use a name and keep your code properly maintainable, and understandable for the person who has to work on it after you're done with it (even if that means you, 3 months from now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its `callee` not `calee`

> Warning: The 5th edition of ECMAScript (ES5) forbids use of arguments.callee() in strict mode. Avoid using arguments.callee() by either giving function expressions a name or use a function declaration where a function must call itself. more details on `caller` `callee`
>
> [Why was the arguments.callee.caller property deprecated in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103598/why-was-the-arguments-callee-caller-property-deprecated-in-javascript/235760#235760)

```
function showFunc() {
    var funcname = arguments.callee.name;
    console.log(funcname);
}
showFunc();
```