# How can I know who is a caller a js function?

Tags: javascript

I have a method which is called by a button and which I can't modify for some reason.

```
<button onclick="onMyButtonClick()">button1</button>
<button>button2</button>

function onMyButtonClick() {
  // how to know who is a caller?
}
```

how to know who is a caller?

UPDATE:

```
<button onclick="onMyButtonClick(123)">button1</button>
<button>button2</button>

function onMyButtonClick(a, b) { // b is undefined
  // how to know who is a caller?
}
```

Comment: `argument.callee.caller`

Comment: You want which button triggered the event?

Comment: You could also use the event object and call `event.target`

Comment: @Ramanlfc, what's argument?

Comment: @user2190492, where to get it?

Comment: Ramanlfc means the `arguments` var.

Comment: do you want the target of the event ?

Comment: @Ramanlfc. "argument.callee.caller". But how can I get "button" or something from that?

Comment: use `event.target` to get  the button

Comment: @Ramanlfc, in fact, argument.callee.caller is equal to "onclick"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103598/why-was-the-arguments-callee-caller-property-deprecated-in-javascript/235760#235760

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee

Comment: What do you mean you "can't modify it for some reason"? Do you not have access to the html file or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this example:

`arguments.callee.caller`
and
`event.target`

https://jsfiddle.net/cb3fcbL6/1

Comment: Neither of these are best practice

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript event.

```
event.srcElement
```

Gives to you the dom element that calls the the function.

See this example:

```js
function onMyButtonClick() {
  alert(event.srcElement.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="onMyButtonClick()">button1</button>
<button onclick="onMyButtonClick()">button2</button>
```

Comment: This is the best answer if the parameters can't be changed. `srcElement` is more descriptive than `target`

Answer (score 0):

Pass `this` as the parameter to the function.

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="onMyButtonClick(this)">button1</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function onMyButtonClick(button) {
    //button is the DOM element that called the function
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution because anybody who goes back to read the code would have no difficulty understanding what you're trying to accomplish. It's self-explanatory.

Comment: except that you've forgotten something.

Comment: If you can't edit the html file though in order to change the parameter, then use Juan's solution `var button = event.srcElement` to get the DOM element. It's just that using `event` would be confusing because it's being used for an unusual purpose.

Comment: @Mario what did I forget?