# what is the arguments variable an instance of?

Tags: javascript, arguments

MDN says it is "[an Array like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)" but does not say what it is an instance of.

It is not an `HTMLCollection` or `NodeList`.

If I call `Object.prototype.toString.call(arguments)` it returns `"[object Arguments]"` but `arguments instanceof Arguments` is an error.

So what is `arguments` an instance of?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So what is arguments an instance of?

It's an instance of `Object`.  There does not appear to be any public `Arguments` constructor that you can use with `instanceof` to identify it that way.

If you want to uniquely identify it, then:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(arguments) === "[object Arguments]"
```

is a safe way to identify it.

Per [section 9.4.4 in the EcmaScript 6 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), the `arguments` object is either an ordinary object or an exotic object.  Here's what the spec says:

> Most ECMAScript functions make an arguments objects available to their
>   code. Depending upon the characteristics of the function definition,
>   its argument object is either an **ordinary object** or an **arguments
>   exotic object**.
>
> An arguments exotic
>   object is an exotic object whose array index properties map to the
>   formal parameters bindings of an invocation of its associated
>   ECMAScript function.
>
> Arguments exotic objects have the same internal
>   slots as ordinary objects. They also have a [[ParameterMap]] internal
>   slot. Ordinary arguments objects also have a [[ParameterMap]] internal
>   slot whose value is always undefined. For ordinary argument objects
>   the [[ParameterMap]] internal slot is only used by
>   Object.prototype.toString (19.1.3.6) to identify them as such.

Since it is an "exotic" object, that essentially means it doesn't follow all the normal and expected conventions.  For example, there is no constructor function from which you can create your own object.  And, because there is no public constructor function, that probably also explains why there's no `instanceof` that you can test on it to uniquely identify it.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the name of the function where `arguments` returned from using `callee.name`

```
function test() {
  this.args = arguments;
}

var obj = new test();

console.log(obj.args.callee.name);
```

---

```
function test() {
  return arguments
}

console.log(test().callee.name);
```

See also [Why was the arguments.callee.caller property deprecated in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103598/why-was-the-arguments-callee-caller-property-deprecated-in-javascript/) , [Arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Comment: Can't do this in `strict` mode.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes; included link to more details.