# Get the name of a function which has this function in its parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I'd like to know if it's possible to get the name of the function which has this function in its parameters.

A practical example:

```
function foo () {
    console.log(somethingHere) --> 'bar'
    return true;
}

function bar (param1, param2) {}

bar(foo(), 'something');
```

Comment: Why do you need it ? Do pass it as string as another argument...

Comment: Your question is not very clear. besides the call to `bar(foo(), 'something')` actually has a first parameter of `true`

Comment: @showdev Not quite. `foo` isn't called by `bar`, `foo` returns a parameter for `bar`

Comment: Right, bar will in the end work with `true`, but I'm creating a module for this and I'd like to find out who called `foo`, even if it's in the parameters of another function. @showdev: I have tried what was in the answer of that question, since I also found that, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Ah, I see. I also see that [arguments.callee.caller property may now be deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103598/why-was-the-arguments-callee-caller-property-deprecated-in-javascript) anyway :-/

Comment: `bar` didn't call `foo`. `foo` has no way of knowing how its output is used.

Answer (score 0):

[Function.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) would return the name of the function, however in your example, `bar` cannot know the actual name of `foo` because `bar` only receiving the return value of `foo` function not `foo` function itself