# Getting Object Key Name from inside function?

Tags: javascript

Say I have an object like below:

```
var obj = {};
obj.test = function() { console.log(?); }
```

Is there anyway to print out "test", the key that this function is value of, but not know the obj name in advance?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? A function is just a value. It has no idea what object(s) it may or may not be a member of. It could be the value of multiple properties on an object.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this [`Object.keys(this)`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjKjsu6udbTAhVIgI8KHSBeBfgQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2Fkeys&usg=AFQjCNHxNfTCTiOC4tCXBdJjQ2o4l76MOw&sig2=nAqDwCS3rdUf3lrNiz4dwQ) and [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee)

```js
var obj = {};
obj.test = function() {
  var o = arguments.callee;
 Object.values(this).map((a,b)=>{
   if(a==o){
   console.log(Object.keys(this)[b])
   }
  })
}
obj.one = "hi"

obj.test()
```

Comment: That prints out **all** the keys, not just the one that point to the function

Comment: This wouldn't give me the specific key that the function is value of, it just give me all the keys :O

Comment: Wow this actually works, but isn't arguments.callee deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Relationships in JS are one-way.

You could search for a match…

```js
var obj = {};
obj.not = 1;
obj.test = function() {
  var me = arguments.callee;
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(prop) {
    if (obj[prop] === me) {
      console.log(prop);
    }
  });
};

obj.test();
```

But look at this:

```js
var obj = {};
obj.not = 1;
obj.test = function() {
  var me = arguments.callee;
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(prop) {
    if (obj[prop] === me) {
      console.log(prop);
    }
  });
};
obj.test2 = obj.test;
obj.test3 = obj.test;
window.foo = obj.test;

obj.test();
```

The same function now exists on three different properties of the same object … and as a global.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit of a convoluted solution, but this might be useful -

You can have a method that will add functions to your object at a specific key. Using the `bind` method, we can predefine the first argument to the function to be the key that was used to add it.
The function that I am adding to the key is `_template`, it's first argument will always be the key that it was added to.

```js
var obj = {};
    
function addKey(key) {
  obj[key] = _template.bind(null, key)
}
    
function _template(key, _params) {
  console.log('Key is', key);
  console.log('Params are',_params);
}


addKey('foo')
obj.foo({ some: 'data' }) // this will print "foo { some: 'data' }"
```

---

Reference - [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score -1):

You can get the name of the method called with
**arguments.callee.name**

```js
var a ={ runner_function : function(){ console.log(arguments.callee.name ); } };

a.runner_function() //It will return "runner_function"
```

Comment: You probably want to add a disclaimer that `arguments.callee` is deprecated - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103598/why-was-the-arguments-callee-caller-property-deprecated-in-javascript/235760#235760

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for keys that added after object is initialized like in my example. it returns as "" (blank)