# Clear specific timeout

Tags: javascript

How can I clear this timeout:

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    window.setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
}, 1000)
```

`clearTimeout(timeout)` don't working..

Comment: instead of using `window.setTimeout` have you tried changing it to `timeout = setTimeout( .. )` in the function?

Comment: You may want to read [this answer to the question of why `arguments.callee` was removed from recent versions of ECMAScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/235760/215552).

Comment: @PatrickBarr Why would that make any difference?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You have timeout inside timeout :) I think you can make it simpler. Try add clearTimeout(timeout); console.log('been in this line!'); You will know if your code has been entered or not.

Comment: You're only clearing the first timeout, not the inner timeout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting `timeout` to the result of the first call to `setTimeout`, but not any following calls. You probably want

```
var timeout;

timeout = setTimeout(function() {
  timeout = window.setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
}, 10);

clearTimeout(timeout);
```

But this would be better written as

```
function iter() {
  timeout = setTimeout(iter, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the timeout in a variable that is outside of the scope of the recursion. Also avoid using arguments.callee due to IE's limitations. You can check a working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/536vpq19/).

```
var timeout = null;

function updateTimeout() {
    timeout = setTimeout(updateTimeout, 1000)
    console.log('hoi')
}

// Start the timeout
updateTimeout();
```

Comment: No, avoid using `arguments.callee` because it's bad practice and deprecated and won't work at all in strict mode.

Comment: True too, but it's a combination of both

Answer (score 0):

You need to reassign `timeout` each time you set new timeout. And get rid of `arguments.callee`.
Try this working example:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button onclick="myStopFunction()">Stop the alert</button>

<script>
var timeout;

function myFunction() {
    timeout = setTimeout(function timerHandler() {
        timeout = setTimeout(timerHandler, 1000);
    }, 1000)
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}
</script>
```